# Internationalisation of Ajax file explorer

Tags: webdav, ithit-ajax-file-browser

We are trying to be able to use this component with several language (our web application that could include AFE -Ajax file explorer- is multi-lingual).

We would like to know if this component has already language bundles (FR,DE,...)?

Answer (score 1):

Currently Ajax File Browser does not have language bundles. However it fully supports localization. There are two approaches to localization:

1. Localize all strings stored in ITHitAJAXFileBrowser.js file. The strings are not compressed so you can easily replace them with a translated version.
2. Pass localized strings to constructor in Settings.Phrases object. In this case you do not need to edit the original ITHitAJAXFileBrowser.js file.

You can find more details in [Localizing AJAX File Browser](http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajaxfilebrowser/programming/localization) article.